# Pointer To Function With/Without &

Tags: c, pointers

Are there any different between those both (`ptrfun1` and `ptrfun2`)?

```
int fun(int num){
    num *= num;
    return num;
}

int main(){
    int (*ptrfun1)(int num) = fun;
    int (*ptrfun2)(int num) = &fun;
```

Does both point to the function `fun`?

Comment: Also, you can use just `ptrfun1(23);` instead of `(*ptrfun1)(23);`.  It is common to see code written as `if (ptrfun1) ptrfun1(arg);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference at all.

A function *decays* to a function pointer.

Comment: It may be obvious, but pointing it to another function with the same arguments can not be done?

Comment: So long as the function has the same parameters and a *covariant* return type, yes you can use `ptrfun1` and `ptrfun2` to point to another function.

Comment: The one cat proof type. `*****************&&&&&&&&&`